# .rc file vs external xml file

Tags: xml, string

I have a program which needs a help link in the menu. The help link differs depending on the language, version, user type (admin guide or user guide), so there are more than a dozen of links. Should I put all these links in an external XML file under program directory or just hard code in .rc file where has a huge string table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put everything in .rc file it will be bad for re-factoring. If I was you I'd use external XML.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the re-factoring? An example would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You can have xml file on server where you simply change urls and it's changed for every application. you can't do this kind of thing with .rc

Comment: Oh yes, and this shift the task of changing the links from programmers to the documentation guy, and no more rebuild of program for this change. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about whether you want the enduser to be able to see this file or not. As XML is text-based it would be quite easy to change that file.

If the link list does change later on (for example with future updates), it would be much easier to just have an XML file.

In the end, it doesn't matter too much and is just a question of convenience for you. I would go for the XML file as I am used to that method.

Comment: It probaly only contains the versions, languages, and the corresponding links. No dirty little secret in it. Im just struggling with the cons and pros of each way.

Comment: The only difference is, that it is easier to change it (as I already stated). The application does not have to be rebuild for a change. This is btw also what PLB meant. There is also a performance difference if your XML is REALLY large. Not to worry about in this case. ;)